# ASP.NET Validate a label

Tags: asp.net

What is the easiest way to validate a label (automatically shows total of shopping cart) using the asp.net validation controls??

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to validate a label? it's just text no input? Do you mean an input of some kind?

Comment: @James - it sounds odd, but its not entirely improbable, especially if its being dynamically updated client side. I agree its worth making sure that that's what one wants though 'cos it does *sound* odd!

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure why a label needs to be checked, but using a [Custom Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will be the way you need to go. You can write custom code to do almost anything you want. A Good tutiorial on a Basic Custom Validator can be found [here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I don't have comment permissions yet, but I assume you want to have the total of shopping cart to display > 0.

in the code behind, using a `<asp:CustomValidator ID="Validator1" runat="server">` control,

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelCart.Text)))
{
try
{
  int total = int.Parse(labelCart.Text);
  if (!(total <= 0))
  {
     Validator1.ErrorMessage = "You cannot enter less than 0 products to your shopping cart";
     Validator1.IsValid = false;
  }
}
catch {}
}
```